# Spring REST jackson not marshalling on POST request

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc

Im using spring 4 and have added jackson-databind so I can get the request/reponse object marshalled.. It works when I return the object from a GET request, but the POST request object is not being populated.. It is NOT null so it is being instantiated

I have tried it using an HttpEntity for the method param to see if I was getting the JSON object and it was in the body of the entity. I could then manually marshal it..

I'm trying to figure out what is missing or mis-configured to have jackson

This is the method where the object is instantiated but not populated. Im using Spring 4 and the controller is annotated with `@RestController` which combines `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes =  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> getUser(User user) {
    log.debug("got user: " + user.getId());

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Here is the JSON:

```
{
"id": 12,
"lastName": "Test",
"firstName": "Me"
}
```

This is the user object:
    public class User {
    private int id;
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    public User(){}

```
public User(int id, String lname, String fname) {
    this.id = id;
    this.lastName = lname;
    this.firstName = fname;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
}
```

I also have the jackson mapper defined in my context file. Although the docs stated this didn't have to be done. It did work without it

```
<beans:bean
 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `@RequestBody` annotation in your method call

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes =  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity <?> getUser(@RequestBody final User user){
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an annotation call @RequestBody in your method and if I'm not wrong you'll need to add @ResponseBody too.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes =  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> getUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    log.debug("got user: " + user.getId());

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The responsed provided were correct. I did need to add the `@RequestBody` to the method..I mis-read the docs.. it is only the `@ResponseBody` and `@Controller` that are added using `@RestController`. With that I do not need to add the `@ResponseBody` to the return object

Comment: Hi Daniel, it is common good way, if a answer was correct mark it as the correct one, also you could add some comments to it, with any valuable input.